# ¿Como validar una palabra para realizar una operación?

Tags: java

soy nuevo, un cordial saludo para todos los compañeros de este grupo!

Bueno eh empezado a estudiar un poco java, y estoy intentando hacer una calculadora, la idea es que ingresando el nombre de la operación (suma, resta, división) realice la tarea, pero no se como.

Este es mi código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Operaciones{
      public static void main(String args[]){

       Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
       String operacion ="";
       int num_uno = 0, num_dos = 0, resultado = 0;

       System.out.println("¿Que operacion deseas realizar?");
       operacion = teclado.nextLine();

       if(!operacion.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Ingresa el primer valor: ");
        num_uno = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo valor: ");
        num_dos = teclado.nextInt();

        resultado = num_uno + num_dos;
        System.out.println("Resultado Suma: " +resultado);
     }  
       else if(!operacion.isEmpty()){
        resultado = num_uno - num_dos;
        System.out.println("Resultado Resta: " +resultado);  
       }  
        else if (!operacion.isEmpty()){
         resultado = num_uno * num_dos;
        System.out.println("Resultado Multiplicacion: " +resultado);
     } 
        else if (!operacion.isEmpty()){
         resultado = num_uno/num_dos;
        System.out.println("Resultado Division: " +resultado);
      } 
        else{
        System.out.println("Opcion Invalida");
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Ya lo tenías casi resuelto! :) Era sólo elegir cómo identificar las operaciones y validar cada caso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo cambiar un poco el algoritmo, en lugar de ingresar el nombre de la operación (suma, resta, mult,división), ingresa el simbolo de la operación (+,-,*,/):

```
public static void main(String []args){  
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    String operacion ="";
    int num_uno = 0, num_dos = 0, resultado = 0;
    

System.out.println("¿Que operacion deseas realizar?");
operacion = teclado.nextLine();

// +   SUMA
// -   RESTA
// *   MULTIPLICA
// /   DIVIDE

if(!operacion.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Ingresa el primer valor: ");
    num_uno = teclado.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo valor: ");
    num_dos = teclado.nextInt();

 }
 
 if (operacion.equals("+")) {             
    resultado = num_uno + num_dos;
    System.out.println("Resultado Suma: " +resultado);
 }
 else if(operacion.equals("-")){
    resultado = num_uno - num_dos;
    System.out.println("Resultado Resta: " +resultado);  
 }  
 else if (operacion.equals("*")){
     resultado = num_uno * num_dos;
    System.out.println("Resultado Multiplicacion: " +resultado);
 } 
 else if (operacion.equals("/")){
     resultado = num_uno/num_dos;
    System.out.println("Resultado Division: " +resultado);
 } 
 else{
    System.out.println("Operación Invalida");     
 }
```

}//main

Te paso una imagen de una prueba:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva.